# Donut render blurry, but not in viewport

Tags: rendering, blur

As of this moment I am on the final video by the Blender Guru. I could swear I followed all the steps he did. Renders were fine before adding the motion blur. But later, after adding motion blur my renders are blurry. I turned off the motion blur and the render is still blurry.

[image]

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xgWlBbCqvCrpXF_BLcFD3UyheAovYP-c?usp=sharing)

Comment: This looks like Depth of Field setting on the camera is set to an unrealistic f value.  Typically this number should be between 1.4 and 22ish, dependent on scene scale

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)